# an applicable starting project for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, data-mining

I'm supposed to graduate next spring. To be well qualified for the job market next year, I'd like to study hadoop by myself from now on.

Can anyone recommend an applicable starting project for my case? I have already read: "Hadoop, the definitive guide." And my background is about machine learning and data mining.

Thanks,

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit too broad to get you good answers. You need to know yourself what you want to learn in detail.

Both Hadoop and it's machine learning sibling, Mahout, have **open issues** in their bug tracker. So go ahead, **browse through their wish list, and contribute an extension to Hadoop or Mahout**. Putting "Mahout contributor" onto your resumee will definitely help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org), and playing around with it a bit. It's focused on machine learning and data mining, which seems like a good fit.